# Calculated line- I want Yes /No based column

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

I want a Calculated Column in SharePoint 2013 that is based on Yes/No from another Column. So I have a Column with Yes/No called "Error". I have another column that say "Error Id" and it is a calculated column too.

I am using the formula for "Error ID " Column as

```
=IF(Error="yes", (Concatenate("ERR",[ID]))).
```

This worked for when the "Error" column is selected as "Yes" But I want add that if Error Column is "No" then say "N/A" in the same formula.

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you simply need to put "n/a" into the FALSE parameter of the IF statement. I assume that you are aware of the IF() syntax, i.e.

`IF(<condition>, <do when true>, <do when false>)`

So, for your formula that would be

```
=IF(Error="yes", Concatenate("ERR",[ID]),"n/a")
```

I've also removed the superfluous pair or round brackets you had around the concatenate function.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

Comment: Great. Now please accept the answer as described in the [tour]. That is how you say Thank you when someone has helped you here.

Comment: Welcome @Nina to SE community, As you're a new contributor, I would suggest having a quick tour as explained at [tour]! Also, please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it was helpful for you